# How to break requests.exceptions.MissingSchema?

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to loop an API because of its restrictions on how many results I can get per page.

```
def retrieve_all_records(token = token_xxx):
    all_records = []
    headers = {"Authorization": token,
               'accept': "application/json"}
    url = "https://xxxxxxx/api/v1/FoodWaste/Registrations/?LocationId=678"
    while True:
        response = requests.get(url, headers = headers)
        try:
            if response.status_code == 200:
                print(url)
                json_data = json.loads(response.text)
                all_records = all_records + json_data['data']
                url = json_data['nextPage']
            else:
                print('done')
        except requests.exceptions.MissingSchema as e:
            print('# error:', e)
            break
        except requests.exceptions.RequestException as b:
            print('# error:', b)
            break
    return all_records

final = retrieve_all_records()
```

The loop itself works and I have done this before with other API's but, I'm giving this error.

```
  File "<input>", line 24, in <module>
  File "<input>", line 7, in retrieve_all_records
  File "C:\Users\davgia\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 76, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\davgia\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\davgia\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 516, in request
    prep = self.prepare_request(req)
  File "C:\Users\davgia\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 449, in prepare_request
    p.prepare(
  File "C:\Users\davgia\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 314, in prepare
    self.prepare_url(url, params)
  File "C:\Users\davgia\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 388, in prepare_url
    raise MissingSchema(error)
requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL 'None': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http://None?
```

I tried to make some except to see if I could break it, but just doesn't break!

Thanks for reading and I hope anyone can help me!

Comment: `url = json_data['nextPage']` this as somepoint is having no value so returns `None` type. So when you next call requests the value of url is `None`

Comment: yea I know, because the next page has none. For example when the next page in the API is empty, it returns none for next page. That's why I want it to break so I get my data.

Comment: `if url is None: break`

Comment: or put your  `response = requests.get(url, headers = headers)` inside the try block as its this line that throws the exception you want to catch

Comment: ok I will try it ! Will respond later thanks @ChrisDoyle